# How to backup of deploy rails application from server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi I have a ruby on rails app hosted on AWS EC2 and it is using mysql3 as database.Now I have to take backup of the database to my local machine.

Comment: mysql or sqlite3 ?

Comment: @Rohan  You need copy the credentials and database name of production database in to development.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to take backup.

1. Using mysql workbench UI tool connect you database via ssh tunnel.
2. Connect to the AWS EC2 and take backup there itself and copy the backup file using scp command.

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same with a DigitalOcean application with PostgreSql, to do that, this is what I did, for that you will need a ssh connection, everywhere (DigitalOcean... and probably Amazon) explains how to do that

**In the server (AWS in you case):**

make a cron to execute daily a script to make a backup of the database

```
crontrb -e
```

and add, to perform a copy every day at 23:00

```
 23 * * * sh /home/rails/backup/backup_dump.sh
```

create `/home/rails/backup/backup_dump.sh`:

```
NOW=$(date +"%d")
FILE="app_production_$NOW.sql"
pg_dump -U rails -w app_production > /home/rails/backup/$FILE
```

- of course `pg_dump` is what I use to make a backup of my PostgreSql database, in you case with MySQL will need another

**In your local machine:**

Add in `/etc/cron.daily` directory the script file that contains the recover from AWS backup file, and populate:

```
NOW=$(date +"%d") # date - 1... the day before, don't remeber the script sintax
scp -r root@ip_server:/home/rails/backup/app_production_$NOW.sql /local_machine/user/local_backups
```

And that's all, I hope will help you